# How do you euthanize a fish?

Tags: health, psychology, mental-stimulation

My [Green Neon Tetra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_tetra) has [Neon Tetra disease](http://www.fishchannel.com/fish-health/freshwater-conditions/neon-tetra-disease.aspx) and I am wondering if I can euthanize him because he doesn't eat and he is swimming at a strange angle. If you can find any ways that I can humanely euthanize him that would be extremely appreciated.